# Using MSTest unit framework I get the below error

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

MSTest Unit Framework

The type 'TestClassAttribute' exists in both `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possible solutions:

1. Decide, which assembly need to reference and remove second one. 
   When you're creating a UnitTest-Project from the Wizard, there is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` referenced, so i'd try to remove `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework`
2. If the second Assembly (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework`) can't be removed, you can use alias:

   ```
   using mstest = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
   namespace UnitTestProject1
   {
     [mstest.TestClass]
     public class UnitTest1
     {
       [mstest.TestMethod]
       public void TestMethod1()
       {
       }
     }
   }
   ```